# How to assign gRPC message which is a Python keyword

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

The service that I'm using has a ***from*** message type.

```
    message EmailMessage {
            EmailRecipient from = 1;
            repeated EmailRecipient to = 1;
            ....
    }
```

Here is the code snippet of how I'm creating a request for this service in my client.

```
email_message = eaas_pb2.EmailMessage(
    from=email_recipient_from,
    to=email_recipient_to,
    subject=subject,
    purpose=purpose,
    plain_text_body=plain_text_body)
```

I run into a SyntaxError when using this because from is a Python keyword.
So this exact problem has been documented for protobuf [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated?csw=1#keyword-conflicts). 
Is there a solution for this which doesn't involve changing the message declaration? 
gPRC docs don't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a kwargs dictionary solved it for me.

```
 **{
        'from': email_recipient_from,
        'to': [email_recipient_to],
        'cc': [],
        'bcc': [],
        'subject': subject,
        'purpose': purpose,
        'plain_text_body': plain_text_body,
    }
```